# Extracting SQLite database into text fields from specific row

Tags: database, xcode, ios, sqlite, uitextfield

I am trying to connect to a SQLite database and have a method that specifies a specific row from the database (the first column in the database is “ID” and is a primary key) then extract the information from a few other columns in that row and display them in text fields.

This will be used for a simple Trivia game I am making; I will later make a random method that will choose the row at random.

I have been struggling with this problem for several weeks and I have been through loads of tutorials but all of them deal with displaying the data in a table view, I want to display it simply on text fields in a View based app. I am fairly confused at this point so any help starting from loading the database to displaying the data in the text fields would be GREATLY APPRECIATED!

Thanks!

Comment: What language are you writing the app in? When you say a text field, do you mean a TextBox on a Winforms app?

Comment: Hi Martin, my apologies, I am writing the App in xCode for iPhone OS.

Answer (score 0):

Link to `libsqlite3.dylib` (and import `<sqlite3.h>`) to access the power of SQLite. There are a number of lightweight Objective-C front ends and I suggest you pick one. In this example, I use `fmdb` (https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) to read the names of people out of a previously created database:

```
NSString* docsdir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( 
    NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString* dbpath = [docsdir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"people.db"];
FMDatabase* db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:dbpath];
if (![db open]) {
    NSLog(@"Ooops");
    return;
}
FMResultSet *rs = [db executeQuery:@"select * from people"];
while ([rs next]) {
    NSLog(@"%@ %@", 
        [rs stringForColumn:@"firstname"], 
        [rs stringForColumn:@"lastname"]);
}
[db close];
/* output:
Snidely Whiplash
Dudley Doright
*/
```

That illustrates talking to the database; knowing SQL is up to you (and is a different topic). You can include a previously constructed SQLite file in your app bundle, but you can't write to it there; the solution is to copy it from your app bundle into another location, such as the Documents directory, before you start working with it.

Finally, to put strings into text fields (UITextField), set their `text` property. So for example instead of the `while` loop shown above, where I log the database results, I could use those results to set text field values:

```
myTextField.text = [rs stringForColumn:@"firstname"];
myOtherTextField.text = [rs stringForColumn:@"lastname"];
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Matt!

I've tried what you've suggested but I am unclear of two things:

1. The link you supplied for fmdb just goes to a page where you can download a project? Is fmdb supposed to be a framework?

2. In your example you've used people.db, looking at your code structure it looks like your using/saving a database that is in the documents folder bundled with the app. I need to make a pre-existing SQL database that is read only that I will have saved in my projects resources folder. Correct me if I'm worn here?

Thanks again!

Comment: fmdb is just some classes, drag right into your project and use. - The database file can be anywhere; as I said, my app started out by copying the database from the app bundle to the Documents directory before opening it, just in case I wanted to write to it.

Comment: Hi Matt, I've added the classes to my project and imported the .h files, but now I'm having an error "duplicate symbol _main in...." this seems overcomplicated and very code heavy compared with other tutorials on extracting data from a sqlite database, only problem with all the tutorials I've seen is that they all import an entire first column into a table view, I simply need to specify which row from the database and extract the data from that rows columns.

Comment: Man has this been an absolute pain trying to figure out the last few weeks, I really appreciate all the help you've offered, I'm just past frustrated trying to figure out something that should be, and likely is very simple.

Comment: Well, obviously you don't import fmdb.m into your project. That's just there so he's got a standalone test project of his own. What you want are the classes represented by the six FM... files.

Comment: Jez I had added that .m file, my bad! Everything seems to be working all good now, though I am unable to set the text property for my fields. I have all the outlets/connections setup properly, now where in your code does it specify what row its pulling from and how would I set the text property?  Man oh man you've been a HUGE help I really appreciate everything!!

Comment: Nowhere in *my* code does that happen; I'm just fetching everything (`select *`). I told you - learning SQL is a completely different issue and has nothing to do with Cocoa or iPhone. For now, to convince yourself that it is working, just set a couple of UITextField text properties to the values from the first row, or something like that.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks again for the response, your a champ! I do have a pretty good handle on SQL (outside of the iPhone) I'm just really struggling with the syntax to fetch a specific row and set text fields properties to specific columns in the DB. Instead of (select *) what could I use to retrieve the info from columns of a specific row then myTextField.text =.....? I feel like we're just about there and I am so thankful you have been willing to take the time to help a relative noob like me! Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi Matt, maybe you could clear up a few things for me?

1. "people.db" can this be a .sql database I have saved into my resources folder? Does the docsdir stay the same?

2. "select * from people" Is "people" the database table name? Is this where I could specify a row?

3. [rs stringForColumn:@"firstname"]; is "firstname" one of the database column name?

I feel like this solution is just within reach, you would be an absolute savior if we can get this to work! I've tried your code to populate the fields but it doesn't load anything in, I think this is because there is no row selected.